# using google api with in dojo module

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dojo

I want to use Google maps api with in dojo toolkit modüle like this.

```
define(["dojo/dom"], function (dom) {

    var input = dom.byId("searchBox");

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);    
});
```

but this code gives error. **ReferenceError: options is not defined**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define var options and give it value.

If "options" in goole.maps.places.Autocomplete is an optional parameter, you can just call

```
define(["dojo/dom"], function (dom) {

    var input = dom.byId("searchBox");

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);    
});
```

Comment: if I use autocomplete in <script> </script>tag, it is working. But when I use it in module, it is not workign.

Comment: Thannks, I deleted options.